# Use R to make line plot of group means at 3 timepoints?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Sorry I feel like this is a simple question but I have spent hours digging around and cannot figure it out.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID  Condition  Pre_Intimacy  Post_Intimacy  FollowUp_Intimacy
1   1          2             4              4   
2   1          7             6              7
3   2          5             7              5
4   2          6             7              6
5   2          2             1              1
```

I want to create a line plot of this data that looks like the plot I have drawn below.

So essentially, the y axis would be intimacy and the x-axis would be time, but represented categorically as 3 static timepoints rather than a continuous variable. On the plot, there would be two different-colored lines, one for each condition. Each line would have three points - each point would be the mean at a given timepoint: pre, post, and follow-up.

Is there a simple way to do this in R? How do I do it?

I've tried different ways of melting the data into long format but I can't figure out exactly how it should look or how to get it there. Any help would be much appreciated!

[My drawing of the plot I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i8DH.png)

Comment: I recommend spending some time working through R for data science to learn a consistent "tidy" way of doing things. Functions like `pivot_longer()` will make your life easier, as will understanding how `aes()` works in **ggplot**.

Comment: That book looks like a helpful resource, I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to reshape your data frame in a way that allows you to plot as you wish. First, you need to summarise your data to calculate the means of the rows. Then you reshape the data to a long format with appropriate categorical variables. Using the `tidyverse` way.

UPDATED after Emerson's comment to change the legend labels by changing the factor labels of `condition`. Added axis labels, a title and a way to control the plot colours:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(ID = seq(1:5),
               condition = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
               pre_intimacy = c(2, 7, 5, 6, 2),
               post_intimacy = c(4, 6, 7, 7, 1),
               follow_up_intimacy = c(4, 7, 5, 6, 1))

data <- data %>%
  group_by(condition) %>%
  summarise(pre_intimacy = mean(pre_intimacy),
            post_intimacy = mean(post_intimacy),
            follow_up_intimacy = mean(follow_up_intimacy)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains('intimacy'),
               names_to = "period",
               values_to = "intimacy") %>%
  mutate(condition = factor(condition, labels = c("condition 1", "condition 2"))) %>%
  mutate(period = factor(period, levels = c("pre_intimacy", "post_intimacy", "follow_up_intimacy")))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = period, y = intimacy, group = condition, colour = condition, shape = condition)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.1) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("condition 1" = "cadetblue", "condition 2" = "darkred")) +
  labs(x = "Period", y = "Intimacy", title = "Intimacy by period")
```

With this result:

[image]
Note that you have to re-order the levels your x-axis categorical variable (`period`) to prevent that `ggplot` will arrange them in an alphanumerical order. As the factor levels in `period` represent time you would like the value `follow_up_intimacy` to be plotted last even though alphanumerically sorted it would be the first value (as it starts with an `f`).

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked perfectly. I don't really understand this code at all but I was able to modify it so that it worked with my full dataset and produced the result I wanted. Out of curiosity, is there a way to change the key so that the values for "condition" have text labels instead of just 1 and 2?

Comment: I updated my response based on your recent comment. Do up-vote my response if you like it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
DF2 <- melt(DF[,-1],id.vars = 'Condition')
DF2$Condition <- as.factor(DF2$Condition)
#Plot
ggplot(DF2, aes(x=variable,y=value,group=1)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Condition))+geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this way because it's simple, and it seems like it would work, except that my actual dataset has like 50 columns instead of just the 5 I listed here for simplicity's sake. When I used this method, it created a huge, crowded plot with all 50 variables on the x axis. Is there a way to exclude them (or to select only certain variables) so that doesn't happen?

Comment: Hmm actually I figured out how to select and exclude non-consecutive columns when melting so the plot is only including the necessary variables, but it still doesn't seem to work. It now has only 3 variables on the x axis as intended, but it seems to be plotting every value of each variable above that variable, so a ton of points in a straight vertical line, rather than the mean, which would just be a single point above each variable (per condition). Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: `pivot_longer()` makes more sense than `melt()`, and is probably a better entry point for new R folks.